# Android Mysql JSON output format incorrect

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, json

Hi i'm using this code to connect Android to Mysql trough PHP

PHP FILE

```
    <?php

      mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","xxpasswordxx");

      mysql_select_db("peopledata");

      $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");

      while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

              $output[]=$e;

           print(json_encode($output));

    mysql_close();
?>
```

this is java

```
    package com.connector;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class whitehat extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   TextView txt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources 
    // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML. 
    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()); 
    txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); 
    rootLayout.addView(txt); 
    setContentView(rootLayout); 

    // Set the text and call the connect function. 
    txt.setText("Connecting...");
  //call the method to run the data retreival
    txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121));



}
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/hellomysql/mysqlcon.php"; //i use my real ip here



private String getServerData(String returnString) {

   InputStream is = null;

   String result = "";
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1970"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                            ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                            ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                            ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                    );
                    //Get an output to the screen
                    returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return returnString;
}   

}
```

the output is like this

{"birthyear":"1973","id":"1","sex":"1","name":"vlizzard"}

but this is not a correct JSON format! if I comment a part of java like this

```
try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

              /*  Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                        ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                        ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                        ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear") */

                );
                //Get an output to the screen
                returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

works in anyway that means the result from PHP file goes to screen anyway... what is wrong?
can somebody help me please?

Comment: Just checked your JSON, but it's a valid JSON response. So what is the problem?

Comment: I'm unsure how {"birthyear":"1973","id":"1","sex":"1","name":"vlizzard"} is not valid json format. Am I missing something? (plus you forgot to comment out a ");")

Comment: ok, But how it is possible that ... when I comment the last piece of code I get anyway the returnString in that format? should not be different? I jump all the cast process...I'm confuse

Comment: Sorry! I read more a bout the Log !!!  I made confusion about output and Log.... Thank you all guys for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's valid JSON. Why do you assume it isn't? It's probably a problem with the way you're reading the JSON values. They all seem to be returned as strings. Try getString() instead of getInt(), and then convert to int's or other data types if needed.

Comment: Maybe the person is confused that it's outputting to the screen and doesn't realize that log is something different.

Comment: Sorry! I read more a bout the Log !!!  I made confusion about output and Log.... Thank you all guys for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Change to following code

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","xxpasswordxx");
```

instead of

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

I hope it is useful